# android phonegap CSS issue

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

We are developing an application for android with phonegap, HTML, CSS and jquery mobile. We have compiled the application in Eclipse and everything works as it should be work, but when i update CSS styles, this are not changes when compile again.

It is strange because in different emulators and browsers the style changes and looks good.

And here is the link to github Project: https://github.com/Phixin/Paulus-V2.0

Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is rendered differently based on the browser and its version. I advise you to have a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/). Using bootstrap you can view the same styles in all devices including android, iphone and even desktop browser.

Comment: THX! @IllegalArgument you are right, i think i see the problem but i dont know how to resolve. If you see the site works fine, but in safari some media queries dont show... i wanna use some hacks but i dont know how to use it in a media queries